# Failed to resolve: com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0

Tags: android, android-library, circularreveal

I'm trying to import this library (https://github.com/ozodrukh/CircularReveal) to my project by writing: `compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0@aar'`

But I get this error :

```
Error:(25, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0
<a href="openFile">Show in File</a><br><a href="open.dependency.in.project.structure">Show in Project Structure dialog</a>
```

I dont understand why since I have succeded in importing other libraries this way.

Comment: It's using jitpack.io instead of maven central (or) jcentre. Have you added that line ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the Github page of the repository:

> This library is not released in Maven Central, but instead you can use
>   JitPack. Add remote maven url:

```
repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
}
```

Might it be possible you forget to add this to your gradle file?

Answer (score 4):

you should add the repository first, and then the dependency, in your build.gradle(app:module) ,just like this :

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://jitpack.io"
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile ('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:2.0.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

ok, you can do it, i hope this can help you !